# How do I type m≤n in Emacs's Agda mode without it turning into m≰?

Tags: agda, agda-mode

What is the best way to type something like `m≤n` in Emacs's Agda mode?

If I type <kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> I get  `m≰`, which is annoying.

My current workaround is to type <kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> but it is not very ergonomic.

Is there something I can do that doesn't require me to type an useless key and then immediately delete it with backspace?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to exit the "character composition" mode.

So to input`m≤n` you can type <kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>) <kbd>n</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

If you press `C-u C-c =` while your cursor is on the character, you will get information about it. The `input` line details the various ways in which you may input it.

Looks like `\leqslant` doesn't suffer from an additional `n` turning `≤` into `≰`. However it is shorter to type space & then erase it.